# Is promotion of contraception a reason to excommunicate?

Tags: catholicism, politics, contraception

Melinda Gates (wife of Bill Gates) promotes contraception such as condoms and sterilization among many other things. This is against the Catholic teaching. She also claims to be a [practicing catholic](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-3519177/Practicing-Catholic-Melinda-Gates-says-Church-need-agree-disagree-family-planning-promotes-use-birth-control-developing-countries.html).

My question is: Could public promotion of something that is against the teaching of the Catholic Church be used to excommunicate? If yes, why doesn't the Catholic Church excommunicate her? Or who/where can claim the case for excommunication?

Comment: Good question! This question is not one of the nine actions which incur [automatic excommunication.](http://www.catholic.com/quickquestions/apart-from-abortion-are-there-other-sins-that-incur-automatic-excommunication)

Comment: [How many Catholics are excommunicated in an average year?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/45202).     You may find the answers to the above helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Canon 915](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P39.HTM) states:

> Those who have been excommunicated or interdicted after the imposition or declaration of the penalty and **others obstinately persevering in manifest grave sin** are not to be admitted to holy communion.

Those who publicly promote contraception are "persevering in manifest grave sin". It's manifest because it's public; it's grave because sexual sins are always grave matter.

---

> Could public promotion of something that is against the teaching of the Catholic Church be used to excommunicate?

Yes

> If yes, why doesn't the Catholic Church excommunicate her?

Cowardly bishops

> Or who/where can claim the case for excommunication?

Bishops can excommunicate.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer, but an opinion. Bishops clearly have pastoral leeway to handle situations in a number of ways, and excommunication is not something that should be taken lightly. They are also responsible for exercising prudential judgement in determining what is most likely to strengthen the faith of the individual and the rest of the diocese. There is a large amount of information available as to why excommunications are now less commonly used, please reference it in the future.